# libevhtp-1.2.18 doesn't build against libevent 2.1.12-stable

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I'm trying to compile libevhtp-1.2.18. libevent is required.

***UPDATE: I tried with 1.2.16 too with the same result***

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS \n \l
- cmake version 3.16.3
- gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3

I compiled libevent first.

```sh
$ tar xvfz libevent-2.1.12-stable.tar.gz
$ cd libevent-2.1.12-stable/
$ ./configure --prefix /opt/corelibs/libevent-2.1.12
$ make
$ make install
```

I used ld.so.conf files to register the libs.

```sh
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ld_corelibs.conf
/opt/fluzo3_corelibs/msgpack-3.3.0/lib
/opt/fluzo3_corelibs/libevent-2.1.12/lib
$ ldconfig
```

Then, I tried to compile libevhtp

```sh
$ tar xvfz libevhtp-1.2.18.tar.gz
$ cd libevhtp-1.2.18
$ cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/opt/corelibs/libevhtp-1.2.18 ..
```

Running cmake I get an error.

This is the full log.

```sh
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/opt/corelibs/libevhtp-1.2.18 ..
-- Could NOT find ONIGURUMA (missing: ONIGURUMA_LIBRARY ONIGURUMA_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find LIBEVENT (missing: LIBEVENT_LIBRARIES LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find ONIGURUMA (missing: ONIGURUMA_LIBRARY ONIGURUMA_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- ONIGURUMA NOT FOUND, DISABLING REGEX SUPPORT

-- EVHTP_VERSION            :  1.2.18
-- EVHTP_DISABLE_SSL        :  OFF
-- EVHTP_DISABLE_EVTHR      :  OFF
-- EVHTP_DISABLE_REGEX      :  ON
-- EVHTP_BUILD_SHARED       :  
-- EVHTP_USE_JEMALLOC       :  
-- EVHTP_USE_TCMALLOC       :  

-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE         : 
-- CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX     : /opt/corelibs/libevhtp-1.2.18
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR         : /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR : /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR : /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
-- PROJECT_BINARY_DIR       : /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
-- PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR       : /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
-- CMAKE_MODULE_PATH        : /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/cmake
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME        : Linux
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION     : 5.8.0-53-generic
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER         : /usr/bin/cc
-- CMAKE_AR                 : /usr/bin/ar
-- CMAKE_RANLIB             : /usr/bin/ranlib
-- CFLAGS                   :   
                              -O3 -DNDEBUG

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
/root/libevhtp-1.2.18/LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
LIBEVENT_CORE
    linked by target "evhtp" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
    linked by target "example_https_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_https_server" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_extensive" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_proxy" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_query" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_perf" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_request_fini" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_chunked" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_pause" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
LIBEVENT_EXTRA
    linked by target "evhtp" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
    linked by target "evhtp" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
    linked by target "example_https_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_https_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_https_server" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_https_server" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_extensive" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_extensive" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_proxy" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_proxy" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_query" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_query" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_perf" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_perf" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_request_fini" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_request_fini" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_chunked" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_chunked" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_pause" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_pause" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
LIBEVENT_LIBRARY
    linked by target "evhtp" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
    linked by target "example_https_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_https_server" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_extensive" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_proxy" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_query" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_perf" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_request_fini" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_chunked" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_pause" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
LIBEVENT_SSL
    linked by target "evhtp" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
    linked by target "example_https_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_https_server" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_extensive" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_proxy" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_query" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_perf" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_request_fini" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_chunked" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_pause" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
LIBEVENT_THREAD
    linked by target "evhtp" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
    linked by target "example_https_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_https_server" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_extensive" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_proxy" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_client" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_query" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "test_perf" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_request_fini" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_chunked" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_pause" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_vhost" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples
    linked by target "example_basic" in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/examples

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/libevhtp-1.2.18/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/libevhtp-1.2.18/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The errors

```sh
-- Could NOT find LIBEVENT (missing: LIBEVENT_LIBRARIES LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIR) 

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
/root/libevhtp-1.2.18/LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /root/libevhtp-1.2.18
LIBEVENT_CORE
```

Into *CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log* we can see... (This seems not related with libevent)

```sh
Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_6f963/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_6f963.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_6f963.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/libevhtp-1.2.18/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_6f963.dir/HAVE_SYS_TREE.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_6f963.dir/HAVE_SYS_TREE.c.o   -c /root/libevhtp-1.2.18/CMakeFiles/CheckIncludeFiles/HAVE_SYS_TREE.c
/root/libevhtp-1.2.18/CMakeFiles/CheckIncludeFiles/HAVE_SYS_TREE.c:2:10: fatal error: sys/tree.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <sys/tree.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_6f963.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_6f963.dir/HAVE_SYS_TREE.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/libevhtp-1.2.18/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_6f963/fast] Error 2
```

In *../CMakeLists.txt* we can see

```sh
find_package(LibEvent REQUIRED)
list(APPEND LIBEVHTP_EXTERNAL_LIBS ${LIBEVENT_LIBRARIES})
list(APPEND LIBEVHTP_EXTERNAL_INCLUDES ${LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
list(APPEND package_deps LibEvent)
```

In Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS \n \l works fine.

Any idea?

Comment: After `./configure --prefix /opt/corelibs/libevent-2.1.12` it should be `make` and `make install`. Also, as you install libevent under the **custom** prefix, then you need to tell CMake about this prefix. E.g. by passing `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/corelibs/libevent-2.1.12`.

Comment: I'll did make and make install. I forgot write it. But cmake with -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH= it was well wroten.

Comment: If I compile libevent-2.1.12 without prefix, libevhtp-1.2.18 can found the dependencies.

Comment: "If I compile libevent-2.1.12 without prefix ..." - No specifying a prefix means using standard (system) prefix. CMake searches under these prefixes by default.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, exactly.  But why cmake does not find event with -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/corelibs/libevent-2.1.12 ?

Comment: Run `cmake` with additional `--debug-find`. That way CMake will print paths which are searched when looking for a library or a header file. Compare these paths with paths where libevent library and its header file are actually located.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I can't see no difference using --debug-find. (cmake --help does not show this option)

Comment: Hm, it seems that module [FindLibEvent.cmake](https://github.com/criticalstack/libevhtp/blob/develop/cmake/FindLibEvent.cmake), shipped with libevhtp, searches libevent **incorrectly**. E.g. it calls `find_path (LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES event.h)` while the header should be accessed with `event2/event.h` (and they really access that header in [thread.c](https://github.com/criticalstack/libevhtp/blob/master/thread.c). You may report the problem to the developers.